# Convert string to array, that has a lot of white spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have a string similar to this:

The text editor removes all the white spaces, however there are maybe 15-20 white spaces on every new line before the first names

```js
 Jake Senior
                             Stephen Abert
                             Benny Andrnw
                             Jacob Ben Juniour
                             Michael Smith
```

However I'm having trouble in splitting it into an array, as splitting by white spaces creates several emtpy values in the array, I'm also trying to get the both names each time rather than split them in seperate values

Comment: can you show us how you do to split by white space

Comment: Please show the input string defined with Javascript syntax and the expected output

Comment: As mentioned, please provide a valid string with the problematic whitespaces in valid JavaScript syntax.

Answer (score 7):

Split the string by newline (`\n`), then use `trim()` to remove whitespaces in the front and back of the string.

```js
let string = `Jake Senior
                             Stephen Abert
                             Benny Andrnw
                             Jacob Ben Juniour
                             Michael Smith`
                             
let processedString = string.split('\n').map(elem => elem.trim())
console.log(processedString)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to define the pattern (`\s{2,}`). This would mean split string when there are 2 or more spaces.

You will also have to process split value as they can have trailing spaces around them.

```js
var str = ' Jake Senior\
                             Stephen Abert\
                             Benny Andrnw\
                             Jacob Ben Juniour\
                             Michael Smith';
                             
console.log(str.split(/\s{2,}/).map(name => name.trim()));
```

Comment: What happens if somebody accidentally adds an extra space between names?

Comment: Where did the extra ```\``` come from?

Comment: @phuzi `\` is used to create multiline string. Second, user mistakes cannot be covered. There can be a possibility where user may add multiple new lines. That is up to OP to verify every usecase and proceed

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what the line endings are you should probably do something like this:

```js
let input = `Jake Senior
                             Stephen Abert
                             Benny Andrnw
                             Jacob Ben Juniour
                             Michael Smith`;
let result = input.split('\n').map((s) => s.trim());

console.log(result);
```